# How can I iterate over all views known to the data binder?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have three `TextInputEditText` views in my layout where the user can type in specific information.
On the click of a `Button` this information is stored in my database.

After the user clicks this `Button`, I want to clear all `TextInputEditText` fields.
Right now, I am doing this by hardcoding:

```
private fun clearAllEditTextFields() {
        
    Timber.d("clearAllEditTextFields: called")
        
    binding.bookTitleEditText.text = null
    binding.bookAuthorEditText.text = null
    binding.bookPageCountEditText.text = null
        
}
```

Since this is bad, I would like to use a dynamic `for each` loop to identify all views of type `TextInputEditText` known to `binding` and clear their content:

```
private fun clearAllEditTextFields() {
        
    Timber.d("clearAllEditTextFields: called")
        
    for (view in binding.views) {

        if (view is TextInputEditText) {

            view.text = null
        
        }

}
```

Unfortunately, there is no such field `binding.views`.
Is there still a way to achieve this or something with the same properties?

#### What I have tried so far

I have used a `BindingAdapter`. In my `Util` class, where all my extension functions go, I have created an `EditText` extension function `clearText` annotated as `BindingAdapter` and `JvmStatic`:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("clearText")
fun EditText.clearText(@NotNull shouldClear: Boolean) {
        
    Timber.d("clearText: called")
        
    if (shouldClear) text = null
        
}
```

In XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/book_title_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:imeActionId="100"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@={viewModel.bookTitle}"
    app:clearText="@{viewModel.clearAllEditTextFields}"
/>
```

In my `ViewModel` class, I have created a `var clearAllEditTextFields = false` which is modified in the `clearAllEditTextFields()` function which gets called inside my `ViewModel`:

```
...
var clearAllEditTextFields = false
clearAllEditTextFields()
...

private fun clearAllEditTextFields() {
        
    Timber.d("clearAllEditTextFields: called")
        
    clearAllEditTextFields = true
        
}
```

According to Logcat, my extension function is called when my `ViewModel` is initialized. However, when `clearAllEditTextFields()` gets called, it does not trigger a new call to the extension function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `for` loop doesn't exist to loop over the views in the `binding` object and you can try the following to keep your code conscice.

**Scope Functions**

```
    binding.apply{
       bookTitleEditText.text = null
       bookAuthorEditText.text = null
       bookPageCountEditText.text = null
    }
```

scope functions are a good go iff there are few views and we end up with quite a `boiler-plate` code if the number of views is large, in which cases I think `Binding-Adapter` would be a good choice

```
@BindingAdapter("clear_text")
fun EditText.clearText(shouldClear : Boolean?){
   shouldClear?.apply{
       if(shouldClear)
          text = null
   }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
private val _shouldClear = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val shouldClear : LiveData<Boolean>
get() = _shouldClear

fun setClearStatus(status : Boolean){
   _shouldClear.value = status
}

//since clearing a text is an event and not state, reset the clear_status once it's done
fun resetClearStatus(){
  _shouldClear.value = nul
}
```

**XML**

```
<EditText 
  ......
  app:clear_text = "@{yourViewModel.shouldClear}"
  ...... />
```

**ActivityClass**

```
...
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
...


private fun clearAllEditTextFields() {
   yourViewModel.setClearStatus(true)
   yourViewModel.resetClearStatus()        
}
```

Edit:

add `binding.lifecycleOwner = this` in your activity class and its used for observing LiveData with data binding. The view will observe for text changes at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The scope function is not a good practice either as you have to update it whenever you add a new `EditText`, too. Your second method sounds good but it does not work as the changing of `shouldClear` does not trigger a call to `clearText()`. The function is only called once when the layout is inflated.

Comment: probably something wrong on your side, upload the code of what you tried so far

Comment: binding adapter gets notified every time the underlying source value changes

Comment: did you assign lifecycleowner to binding object?

Comment: No, thats what `JvmStatic` is for. I have it in my `Util` class where I would like to keep it. And there is no `binding` in that class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227402/discussion-between-rcs-and-rene-spies).

Answer (score 0):

Create a linearlayout (or similar) called, for example, text_fields_linear layout enclosing all of your textfields. then do:

```
private fun clearAllEditTextFields() {
    for (item in binding.textFieldsLinearLayout) {
        item.text = null
    }
}
```